# Argument 1 must be an iterator - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, csv, iterator

I've got a section of code in a project that's supposed to be reading a CSV file and writing each row to an XLSX file. Right now I'm getting the error "argument 1 must be an iterator" when I run via command line.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import os
import openpyxl
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook

...

plannum = 4

...

alldata_sheetname = ("All Test Data " + str(plannum))
wb = load_workbook("testingtemplate.xlsx", keep_vba=True)

...

ws_testdata = wb.get_sheet_by_name(alldata_sheetname)

...

with open("testdata.csv", 'r') as csvfile:
    table = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in table:
        ws_testdata.append(row)

csv_read = csv.reader(csvfile)

...
```

And the specific error reads: "TypeError: argument 1 must be an iterator", and is referencing the last line of code I've provided.

Since it didn't complain about the first time I used `csvfile`, would it be better if I did something like `csvfile = open("testdata.csv", "r")` instead of using the `with` (and is that what I'm doing wrong here)? If that's the case, is there anything else I need to change?

Thanks to anyone who helps!!

Comment: You've closed the file by the time you get to `csv_read = csv.reader(csvfile)`. What is that second step meant to do?

Comment: The next few lines of code grab a few variables from the CSV before proceeding. `gcount = sum(1 for row in csv_read)` is the next line, and that's used later on where I'm manipulating data within the xlsx file.

Comment: Ok then you can open the file again using another `with` statement.

Comment: Would it be better to just do:
`csvfile = open("testdata.csv", "r")`, then do everything right there, then do `csvfile.close()`? It sounds like that's what you mean, and if I store what I need in variables I can get them later even with the file closed, right?

Comment: Yes you could do that. And storing what you need in variables is a good idea so you don't have to iterate over the file twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've closed the file by the time you get to `csv_read = csv.reader(csvfile)`. Alternately you can keep the file open and store what you need in variables so you don't have to iterate over the file twice. E.g.:

```
csvfile = open("testdata.csv", "r")
table = csv.reader(csvfile)
for row in table:
    ws_testdata.append(row)
    # store what you need in variables
csvfile.close()
```