# How to change a .csv into lists and vice versa in python?

Tags: python, list, csv

I need to split a .csv file:

```
user1,pass1,email1
user2,pass2,email2
user3,pass3,email3
```

into 3 lists that can be called upon and appended too seperately.

```
with open('userdata.csv', 'r') as f:
    userlist = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(f)]
    passlist = [row[1] for row in csv.reader(f)]
    emaillist = [row[2] for row in csv.reader(f)]
print(userlist)
print(passlist)
print(emaillist)
```

I need this code to return:

```
['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
['pass1', 'pass2', 'pass3']
['email1', 'email2', 'email3']
```

but this is what I get:

```
['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
[]
[]
```

Once this works, I also need a way to write it back as a .csv that will be in the exact format it was when I called it but with added information so it can be called again whenever needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to consume the csv file three times by calling `csv.reader(f)` repeatedly.

You can instead store the rows in a temporary list and get columns from that list.

```
with open('userdata.csv', 'r') as f:
    rows = list(csv.reader(f))
    userlist = [row[0] for row in rows]
    passlist = [row[1] for row in rows]
    emaillist = [row[2] for row in rows]
```

A more elegant way of picking out columns from rows would be through the use of `zip`:

```
with open('userdata.csv', 'r') as f:
    userlist, passlist, emaillist = zip(*(row for row in csv.reader(f)))
```

For writing the csv file, `zip` can be used in the other direction, to convert columns back to rows:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows(zip(userlist, passlist, emaillist))
```

Comment: Do you mean doing `userlist = userlist + ('user4',)` for each column?

This would work but I don't think it's either elegant or readable:
`row =
userlist, passlist, emaillist = tuple(map(lambda x, y: x+(y,), (userlist, passlist, emaillist),  ('user4', 'pass4', 'email4')))`

It might be better to just operate on rows, i.e. `rows = list(csv.reader(f))`. Then the row additions would be as simple as `rows.append(['user4', 'pass4', 'email4'])`. In this case you wouldn't even needs the `zip`s above.

Comment: If you read the rows with `rows = list(csv.reader(input_file))`, and only wrote the rest of code to use `rows`, meaing you didn't use `userlist`, `passlist` and `emaillist`, then you can write it to a file with `csv.writer(f).writerows(rows)`.

Comment: You're probably using a closed file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350086/argument-1-must-be-an-iterator-what-am-i-doing-wrong